# Explicit solution of a Hamiltonian system

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

It is well-known that the following Hamiltonian system 
\begin{eqnarray}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=&y,\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=&x(-1+x^2),
\end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
with 
$$ H(x,y)=\frac{x^2}2+\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}$$
has the solution
$$ x=\tanh\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt2}\right),\qquad y=\frac1{\sqrt2}\text{sech}^2\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt2}\right) $$
such that $H(x,y)=\frac14$.

Now consider the following Hamiltonian system
\begin{eqnarray}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=&y,\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=&x(-1+x^4),
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
with 
$$ H(x,y)=\frac{x^2}2+\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^6}{6}$$
and I want to find the explicit solution such that $H(x,y)=\frac{1}{3}$. I tried many ways to get the solution but failed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edited.

Surprisingly, there is an elementary solution, if I made no mistake in
the following computation.

Your equation is equivalent to
$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{1}{3}(x^6-3x^2+2),$$
(I just plugged $y=dx/dt$ to your Hamiltonian, and used its value $H=1/3$.)
This equation is separable,
$$\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^6-3x^2+2}}=:I$$
and requires inversion of the integral.

To reduce it
to a standard integral, change $x^2=1/(u+1), \; dx=-(1/2)(u+1)^{-3/2}du,$ and the integral becomes
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{2u+3}}.$$
The inverse function to this integral is elementary. Integrating and returning to the original variables, I obtained the general solution
$$x(t)=\frac{2\sinh(t+c)}{\sqrt{6+4\sinh^2(t+c)}}.$$
Can you check this computation?

Of course, your value $1/3$ for the Hamiltonian is crucial here. With
some other value you obtain a much more complicated integral which cannot be expressed in elementary functions. Where did this $1/3$ come from?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I wanted.

Comment: Note it is much clearer than before. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @xpaul: tell me where your $1/3$ comes from.

Comment: 1/3 is from fact that when $H(x,y)=\alpha$ passes through the separatrices $(\pm1,0)$, $\alpha=1/3$.

Comment: If I plug in your $x(t)$, I get $y=x'(t)=\frac{\sinh (c+2 t)}{\sqrt{\frac{\cosh (c+2 t)+1}{\cosh (c+2 t)+2}} (\cosh (c+2 t)+2)^2}$ but I find $\frac{x^2}2+\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^6}6\neq\frac13$.

Comment: I found that $I=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{2u+3}}$ instead of $I=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{2u+3}}$.

Comment: Now I fixed your computation.

Comment: @xpaul how did you get the solution for the first system?

Comment: @TheMathematician Which system?

Comment: @xpaul this system 

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=y,\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=x(-1+x^2).\\
\end{align*}$$

 I have this similar system $y''(x) = \frac{1}{2} (y^3 - u)$ which has the solution $y = \tanh(x/2)$ but I could not get the result by integration.

Comment: Please go to Guckenheimer and Holmes' book: Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of Vector Fields for reference.